# Databinding to a static property (singleton)

Tags: c#, data-binding, static, combobox

I have a fully lazy singleton and a win form,
I want to bind controls to properties in instance of the singeton.
I have a combobox in the form that have tow way bind to a property in the singleton.
The combobox have a datasource (list), when the form loads and the combobox was loded with   a selected item, the selected item didnt update in the singleton property.
for example if on load the combobox have a selecte value "1" the singleton property will   not get this value and will stay null, if after that I will select in the combobox a   difrent value it will update the property correctly.
Is there a way to solevd it?

```
   avilibaleLinesComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Settings.Instance, 
              "CallBackExtn",    true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    [Serializable()]
    public class Settings
    {
    private static volatile Settings instance;

    private Settings() { }

    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null) 
            {
                lock (syncRoot) 
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = loadSettingsFromFile();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ConnectionString")]
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface on your class.

Like this (note: check if the serializing/deserializing still works as expected):

```
[Serializable()]
public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private static volatile Settings instance;

    private Settings() { }

    public static Settings Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null)  {
                lock (syncRoot) {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = loadSettingsFromFile();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private string _connectionString;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ConnectionString")]
    public string ConnectionString {
        get { return _connectionString; }
        set {
            if (value != _connectionString) {
                _connectionString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ConnectionString");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null) {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Maarten thank you for your answare, the problem is that the combobox dont update the singleton on the load of the form. for example if on load the combobox have a selecte value "1" the singleton property will not get this value and will stay null, if after that I will select in the combobox a difrent value it will update the property correctly.